# How to Implement search through an array of nested objects consisting of all types of data types? In simple term I want to search through the table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, search, next.js

```
[
    
    {
        "address": {
            "address_1": "Jalna",
            "address_2": "",
            "city": "Jalna",
            "province": "Maharashtra",
            "province_code": "",
            "zip": "757435",
            "country": "India",
            "country_code": "IN",
            "phone": ""
        },
        "geo_cordinates": {
            "title": "Jalna, Maharashtra, India",
            "latLng": "19.8346659,75.88163449999999",
            "lat": "19.8346659",
            "lng": "75.88163449999999"
        },
        "_id": "630dce41d0abb7a0deed828a",
        "title": "MA",
        "description": "",
        "holdInventory": false,
        "storePickupAllowed": false,
        "rules": [],
        "location_type": "CUSTOM",
        "createdAt": "2022-08-30T08:45:53.211Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-08-30T08:45:53.211Z"
    },
    {
        "address": {
            "address_1": "Jarul",
            "address_2": "",
            "city": "Mayurbhanj",
            "province": "Odisha",
            "province_code": "",
            "zip": "757046",
            "country": "India",
            "country_code": "IN",
            "phone": ""
        },
        "geo_cordinates": {
            "title": "Jarul, Odisha 757046, India",
            "latLng": "22.4131695,86.09850689999999",
            "lat": "22.4131695",
            "lng": "86.09850689999999"
        },
        "_id": "630dce65d0abb7a0deed8296",
        "title": "OR",
        "description": "",
        "holdInventory": false,
        "storePickupAllowed": false,
        "rules": [],
        "location_type": "CUSTOM",
        "createdAt": "2022-08-30T08:46:29.695Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-08-30T08:46:29.695Z"
    },
    {
        "address": {
            "address_1": "Guwahati",
            "address_2": "",
            "city": "Kamrup",
            "province": "Assam",
            "province_code": "",
            "zip": "753223",
            "country": "India",
            "country_code": "IN",
            "phone": ""
        },
        "geo_cordinates": {
            "title": "Guwahati, Assam, India",
            "latLng": "26.1157917,91.7085933",
            "lat": "26.1157917",
            "lng": "91.7085933"
        },
        "_id": "630dce94d0abb7a0deed82a2",
        "title": "AS",
        "description": "",
        "holdInventory": false,
        "storePickupAllowed": false,
        "rules": [],
        "location_type": "CUSTOM",
        "createdAt": "2022-08-30T08:47:16.898Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-08-30T08:47:16.898Z"
    }
]
```

Consider the above array of nested objects.
If a user tries to search for say "75" it should search through the object (irrespective of the key) for matches and return all filtered-out matching array objects.

Another example is, If someone wants to find all the objects matching "ja", then the search should go throughout the object and search in the object's values to find a match, if there is a nested object then it should also look inside it and match the searched text within the nested object values.
I hope this is clear

My code:-

```
recursiveObjArraySearch(locations);

    function recursiveObjArraySearch(data) {
        recursivObjectSearch(data, (filteredData) => {
           console.log(filteredData);//*->Output
        });
    }

    function recursivObjectSearch(data, cb) {
        let filtered = data.filter(function (obj) {
            return inObjectSearch(obj);
        });
        cb(filtered);
    }

    function inObjectSearch(obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj).some(function (key) {
            if (typeof obj[key] === "string") {
                if (((obj[key]).toLowerCase()).includes(searchingText.toLowerCase())) {
                    return (obj[key]);
                }
            } else if (typeof obj[key] === "boolean") {
                if ((obj[key]).toString() == (searchingText)) {
                    return (obj[key]);
                }
            } else if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
                inObjectSearch(obj);
            }
            if ((obj[key]) instanceof Array) {
                recursiveObjArraySearch(obj[key]);
            }
        })
    }
```

I tried it this way, but I think it's too hectic and this throws an error too **Maximum call stack size exceeded**

Thank You!

Comment: `.filter()` on the array, using `Object.entries()`on the objects. And then `.contains()` some way. You show no code, just a requirement, so we cannot help you debug your own solution.

Comment: Did you encounter problems implementing this?  What problems?  We can help with those questions.

Comment: I have added my code. Please help me out with this @Shilly

Comment: Maximum call stack size exceeded. This is the error @James

Answer (score 0):

Max call stack exceeded is caused by

```
else if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
  inObjectSearch(obj);
}
```

Try `inObjectSearch(obj[key])`

Full code snippet

```js
const locations = [
    
    {
        "address": {
            "address_1": "Jalna",
            "address_2": "",
            "city": "Jalna",
            "province": "Maharashtra",
            "province_code": "",
            "zip": "757435",
            "country": "India",
            "country_code": "IN",
            "phone": ""
        },
        "geo_cordinates": {
            "title": "Jalna, Maharashtra, India",
            "latLng": "19.8346659,75.88163449999999",
            "lat": "19.8346659",
            "lng": "75.88163449999999"
        },
        "_id": "630dce41d0abb7a0deed828a",
        "title": "MA",
        "description": "",
        "holdInventory": false,
        "storePickupAllowed": false,
        "rules": [],
        "location_type": "CUSTOM",
        "createdAt": "2022-08-30T08:45:53.211Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-08-30T08:45:53.211Z"
    },
    {
        "address": {
            "address_1": "Jarul",
            "address_2": "",
            "city": "Mayurbhanj",
            "province": "Odisha",
            "province_code": "",
            "zip": "757046",
            "country": "India",
            "country_code": "IN",
            "phone": ""
        },
        "geo_cordinates": {
            "title": "Jarul, Odisha 757046, India",
            "latLng": "22.4131695,86.09850689999999",
            "lat": "22.4131695",
            "lng": "86.09850689999999"
        },
        "_id": "630dce65d0abb7a0deed8296",
        "title": "OR",
        "description": "",
        "holdInventory": false,
        "storePickupAllowed": false,
        "rules": [],
        "location_type": "CUSTOM",
        "createdAt": "2022-08-30T08:46:29.695Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-08-30T08:46:29.695Z"
    },
    {
        "address": {
            "address_1": "Guwahati",
            "address_2": "",
            "city": "Kamrup",
            "province": "Assam",
            "province_code": "",
            "zip": "753223",
            "country": "India",
            "country_code": "IN",
            "phone": ""
        },
        "geo_cordinates": {
            "title": "Guwahati, Assam, India",
            "latLng": "26.1157917,91.7085933",
            "lat": "26.1157917",
            "lng": "91.7085933"
        },
        "_id": "630dce94d0abb7a0deed82a2",
        "title": "AS",
        "description": "",
        "holdInventory": false,
        "storePickupAllowed": false,
        "rules": [],
        "location_type": "CUSTOM",
        "createdAt": "2022-08-30T08:47:16.898Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-08-30T08:47:16.898Z"
    }
];


const searchingText = "CUSTOM";

recursiveObjArraySearch(locations);

    function recursiveObjArraySearch(data) {
        recursivObjectSearch(data, (filteredData) => {
           console.log(filteredData);//*->Output
        });
    }

    function recursivObjectSearch(data, cb) {
        let filtered = data.filter(function (obj) {
            return inObjectSearch(obj);
        });
        cb(filtered);
    }

    function inObjectSearch(obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj).some(function (key) {
            if (typeof obj[key] === "string") {
                if (((obj[key]).toLowerCase()).includes(searchingText.toLowerCase())) {
                    return (obj[key]);
                }
            } else if (typeof obj[key] === "boolean") {
                if ((obj[key]).toString() == (searchingText)) {
                    return (obj[key]);
                }
            } else if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
                inObjectSearch(obj[key]);
            }
            if ((obj[key]) instanceof Array) {
                recursiveObjArraySearch(obj[key]);
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Unhandled Runtime Error

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: In this line
   return Object.keys(obj).some(function (key) {

Comment: I can't reproduce your new error.  Glad we fixed your old error though!

Comment: This is strange. I am still getting the error "Cannot convert undefined or null to object". Is there any other way to achieve the same?? @James